# AnonymousUser error on unauthenticated route Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am basically a FE developer. Recently I am trying to edit a Django project and remove authentication from an api. So after removing the authentication and trying to get the data without the token it shows an anonymous error. Works good for valid user

```
django_1        |     return method(value)
django_1        |   File "/app/deals/serializers.py", line 285, in get_already_liked
django_1        |     return usr.is_liking_deal(deal_obj=obj)
django_1        | AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'is_liking_deal'
```

Here is the specific code in the serializers

```
    def get_already_liked(self, obj):
      usr = self.context["request"].user
      return usr.is_liking_deal(deal_obj=obj)
```

After digging into the issue and researching I found out it is an issue with the model and primary key. as I am not sending an user through authentication Django is taking it as AnonymousUser and in the model AnonymousUser doesnt have any primary key.Here is the related code from the model (I think)

```
class DealReactionManager(models.Manager):
    @staticmethod
    def is_user_liking_deal(user, deal):
        """Has user liked the deal already?"""
        try:
            DealReaction.objects.get(user=user, deal=deal)
            return True
        except DealReaction.DoesNotExist:
            return False


class DealReaction(BaseModel):
    deal = models.ForeignKey(to="deals.Deal", related_name="reactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=get_user_model(), related_name="reactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = DealReactionManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("deal", "user")
```

What I can understand from this is, after calling the deals api it looks for the liked deals by user as well as the other deals. I need to make it like if there is user it will go search for the already liked deals+other deals if not then it will only return the deals.
How can I achieve the solution? Sorry I dont have any backend developer around atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it simply by checking an authentication in my serializer.

```
def get_already_liked(self, obj):
    if self.context["request"].user.is_authenticated:
        return self.context["request"].user.is_liking_deal(deal_obj=obj)
```